# Combining two scripts

Tags: hc-sr04

I'm trying to combine two scripts I've found. One to get my remote control model to work via a controller and the other to enable 6 ultrasound modules I have. When I omit the code highlighted in "THIS SECTION" (for the ultrasound modules) the controller and model works fine but when I put it in (to enable to ultrasound modules), the controller becomes unresponsive and the wheels spin uncontrollably.

I'm assuming it's something to do with having what should be two seperate loop sections combined into one?

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks

```
//This section defines all the pin data and  to be used within the program loop.

//The following four lines set the pin numbers for the PS2 controller.
#define PS2_DAT        11 //Data pin.
#define PS2_CMD        10 //Command pin.
#define PS2_SEL        9  //Attention pin.
#define PS2_CLK        8  //Clock pin.

//The following six lines set the pin numbers for the motor module.
#define IN1     33 //Positive polarity for the right sided wheels.
#define IN2     35 //Negative polarity for the right sided wheels.
#define IN3     37 //Positive polarity for the left sided wheels.
#define IN4     39 //Negative polarity for the left sided wheels.
#define ENA     31 //Jumper pin start.
#define ENB     41 //Jumper pin end.

//The analogue values read from the PS2 contoller.
int LX = 0;                   
int LY = 0;
int RX = 0;
int RY = 0;

//The following twelve lines set pin numbers for the ultrasonic sensors. 
int trigPin1=7; //Front transmitter (Object ahead detection).
int echoPin1=6; //Front receiver.
int trigPin2=5; //Right transmitter (Lane keeping).
int echoPin2=4; //Right receiver.
int trigPin3=3; //Rear right transmitter (Right blindspot detection).
int echoPin3=2; //Rear right receiver.
int trigPin4=14; //Rear centre transmitter (Parking sensor).
int echoPin4=15; //Rear centre receiver.
int trigPin5=16; //Rear left transmitter (Left blindspot detection).
int echoPin5=17; //Rear left receiver.
int trigPin6=19; //Left transmitter (Lane keeping).
int echoPin6=18; //Left receiver.

// This section sets the modes of PS2 controller.
//#define pressures   true
#define pressures   false
#define rumble      true
//#define rumble      false

PS2X ps2x; //Creates PS2 controller class.
int error = 0;
byte type = 0;
byte vibrate = 0;

void setup() {

Serial.begin (9600); //Opens the sensor serial ports and sets data rate to 9600bps
  pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin4, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin5, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin6, INPUT);

  pinMode(IN1,  OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN2,  OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ENB, LOW);

  delay(300);  //Added delay to give the wireless PS2 module time to start up before configuring it.

  //Checks for errors determined by pin data: GamePad(clock, command, attention, data, pressures, rumble) 
  error = ps2x.config_gamepad(PS2_CLK, PS2_CMD, PS2_SEL, PS2_DAT, pressures, rumble);

  if (error == 0) {
    Serial.print("Found Controller, configured successful ");
  }
  else if (error == 1)
    Serial.print("No controller found, check wiring");

  else if (error == 2)
    Serial.print("Controller found but not accepting commands");

  else if (error == 3)
    Serial.print("Controller refusing to enter Pressures mode, may not support it.");
  }

void loop() {
---------------------------------------THIS SECTION------------------------------
long duration1, distance1;
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, HIGH);**
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  duration1 = pulseIn(echoPin1, HIGH);
  distance1 = (duration1/2) / 29.1;

   if (distance1 >= 500 || distance1 <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print ( "Sensor1  ");
    Serial.print ( distance1);
    Serial.println("cm");
  }

  long duration2, distance2;
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  duration2 = pulseIn(echoPin2, HIGH);
  distance2 = (duration2/2) / 29.1;

   if (distance2 >= 500 || distance2 <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Sensor2  ");
    Serial.print(distance2);
    Serial.println("cm");
  }
  long duration3, distance3;
  digitalWrite(trigPin3, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  duration3 = pulseIn(echoPin3, HIGH);
  distance3 = (duration3/2) / 29.1;

   if (distance3 >= 500 || distance3 <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Sensor3  ");
    Serial.print(distance3);
    Serial.println("cm");
  }
  long duration4, distance4;
  digitalWrite(trigPin4, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  duration4 = pulseIn(echoPin4, HIGH);
  distance4 = (duration4/2) / 29.1;

   if (distance4 >= 500 || distance4 <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Sensor4  ");
    Serial.print(distance4);
    Serial.println("cm");
  }
  long duration5, distance5;
  digitalWrite(trigPin5, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  duration5 = pulseIn(echoPin5, HIGH);
  distance5 = (duration5/2) / 29.1;

   if (distance5 >= 500 || distance5 <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Sensor5  ");
    Serial.print(distance5);
    Serial.println("cm");
  }
  long duration6, distance6;
  digitalWrite(trigPin6, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  duration6 = pulseIn(echoPin6, HIGH);
  distance6 = (duration6/2) / 29.1;

   if (distance6 >= 500 || distance6 <= 0){
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print("Sensor6  ");
    Serial.print(distance6);
    Serial.println("cm");
  }
---------------------------------------------END----------------------------------------

  ps2x.read_gamepad(false, vibrate); //read controller and set large motor to spin at 'vibrate' speed

  delay(50);
  if (ps2x.Button(PSB_L1))
  {
    LY = ps2x.Analog(PSS_LY); //receive values from p22 joystick
    LX = ps2x.Analog(PSS_LX);
  }
  if (ps2x.Button(PSB_R1))
  {
    RY = ps2x.Analog(PSS_RY);
    RX = ps2x.Analog(PSS_RX);
  }
  if (LY > 200 || RY > 200) //check if the joystick pushed up side
  {
    REV();
  }
  if (LY < 100 || RY < 100)
  {
    forward();
  }
  if (LX < 100 || RX < 100)
  {
    left();
  }
  if (LX > 200 || RX > 200)
  {
    right();
  }
  if(LX == 128 && LY == 128 && RX == 128 && RY == 128)
  {
    waithere();
  }
LY = LX = 128;         //return to default vlaues
RY = RX = 128;         //return to default values
}

void forward()
{
  digitalWrite(ENA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ENB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
}
void REV()
{
  digitalWrite(ENA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ENB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
}
void left()
{
  digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ENB, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
}
void right()
{
  digitalWrite(ENA, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ENB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
}
void waithere()
{
  digitalWrite(ENA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ENB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
}
```

Comment: `pulseIn()` has a standard timeout of 1s. Try to reduce it and see, if it works better

Comment: you can simpify your code if you use arrays to hold variables ... `trigPin[]`, `echoPin[]`, `duration[]`, `distance[]` ... then you can use a `for` loop to iterate through the six sensors, instead of repeating code